# Can I link my business page to another Facebook account after my previous account is disabled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I had a Facebook account that was linked to my business page. I used to share my business page to more community groups to get more likes and follows.
Then Facebook disabled my Facebook account, so can I get my business page anyway to link it to another page?